# navigationItem.title from UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

Navigation Bar title is not appearing according to the Selected Cell.

I have the Navigation View Controller inside a Container View.
The Container View is in ViewController.

ViewController:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "embedseg" {

        guard let splitViewController = segue.destination as? UISplitViewController,
            let leftNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.first as? UINavigationController,
            let masterViewController = leftNavController.topViewController as? MasterViewController,
            //let detailViewController = splitViewController.viewControllers.last as? DetailViewController
            let rightNavController = splitViewController.viewControllers.last as? UINavigationController,
            let detailViewController = rightNavController.topViewController as? DetailViewController

            else { fatalError() }

        let firstMonster = masterViewController.monsters.first
        detailViewController.monster = firstMonster

        masterViewController.delegate = detailViewController

        detailViewController.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = true
        detailViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem

        //detailViewController.navigationItem.title = "Hello" <-- tested this, it worked.

        //detailViewController.navigationItem.title = cell.textLabel?.text <-- this didn't work.

        //detailViewController.navigationItem.title = monster.name <-- and this didn't work.                        
    }
}
```

MasterViewController:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    let monster = monsters[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = monster.name

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you select the cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

     let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! YourCellClassName

     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "embedseg", sender:cell.textLabel?.text)
}
```

in prepareforSegue

```
let cellText = sender as! String

detailViewController.navigationItem.title = cellText
```

Comment: Isn't this going to call "prepareForSegue" twice if he set segues using storyboards?

Comment: in storyboard a segue can be attached to action of a control otherwise he has to do it with **performSegue** in code

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `monster` and `cell` are defined inside

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {}
```

but not inside

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){}
```

If you have set your segues using the storyboard you can do something like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell {
        detailViewController.navigationItem.title = cell.textLabel?.text
    }
}
```

or something like this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?){
    if let cell = sender as? UITableViewCell {
        let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: cell)
        detailViewController.navigationItem.title = monsters[indexPath.row].name
    }
}
```

In the first case you cast "sender" as the cell so you can access it's values, in the second case you cast "sender" as the cell, you find what is it's indexPath and then you use the indexPath to find the correct "monster" using you array `monsters`